# JQuery UI Tabs: Ajax loading of content automatically halts in firebug

Tags: ajax, firebug, jquery-ui-tabs

I have following html:

```
$(function() {          
    $("#tabs").tabs();                      
});
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="content/intro.html">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a href="content/searching.html">Searching</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The issue is that when clicking on a tab firebug (in Firefox 11) opens and halts script execution at line 181 of the jquery-ui-min.js javascript file. If I then press F8 (continue) content loads correctly and there is no error displayed.
(No error also in IE8). How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because an exception is caught at that place. (using non-minfied version). Comment says that this is caused due to a race condition. The exception is caught and hence no further error and execution can continue. However firebug per default seems to stop execution whenever an exception happens.